# Calculating a file's mean value of data bytes

Tags: c++, c++20, unordered-map, accumulate

Just for fun, I am trying to calculate a file's mean value of data bytes, essentially replicating a feature available in an already existing tool ([ent](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/)). Basically, it is simply the result of summing all the bytes of a file and dividing by the file length. If the data are close to random, this should be about 127.5.  I am testing 2 methods of computing the mean value, one is a simple `for` loop which works on an `unordered_map` and the other is using [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) directly on a `string` object.

Benchmarking both methods show that it is much slower to use `std::accumulate` than a simple `for` loop.  Also, mesured on my system, on average, `clang++` is about 4 times faster for the accumulate method than `g++`.

So here are my questions:

1. Why is the `for` loop method producing bad output at around 2.5GB input for `g++` but not with `clang++`.  My guess is I am doing things wrong (UB probably), but they happen to work with `clang++`. **(solved and code modified accordingly)**
2. Why is the `std::accumulate` method so much slower on `g++` with the same optimization settings?

Thanks!

---

Compiler info (target is `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`):

`clang version 11.1.0`

`gcc version 11.1.0 (GCC)`

Build info:

`g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++2a main.cpp -o main-g`

`clang++  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++20 main.cpp -o main-clang`

Sample file (using random data):

`dd if=/dev/urandom iflag=fullblock bs=1G count=8 of=test-8g.bin` (example for 8GB random data file)

Code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

auto main(int argc, char** argv) -> int {
  using std::cout;

  std::filesystem::path file_path{};

  if (argc == 2) {
    file_path = std::filesystem::path(argv[1]);
  } else {
    return 1;
  }

  std::string input{};
  std::unordered_map<char, int> char_map{};

  std::ifstream istrm(file_path, std::ios::binary);
  if (!istrm.is_open()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file");
  }

  const auto file_size = std::filesystem::file_size(file_path);
  input.resize(file_size);
  istrm.read(input.data(), static_cast<std::streamsize>(file_size));

  istrm.close();

  // store frequency of individual chars in unordered_map
  for (const auto& c : input) {
    if (!char_map.contains(c)) {
      char_map.insert(std::pair<char, int>(c, 1));
    } else {
      char_map[c]++;
    }
  }

  double sum_for_loop = 0.0;

  cout << "using for loop\n";
  // start stopwatch
  auto start_timer = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  // for loop method
  for (const auto& item : char_map) {
    sum_for_loop += static_cast<unsigned char>(item.first) * static_cast<double>(item.second);
  }

  // stop stopwatch
  cout << std::chrono::duration<double>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start_timer).count() << " s\n";

  auto mean_for_loop = static_cast<double>(sum_for_loop) / static_cast<double>(input.size());

  cout << std::fixed << "sum_for_loop: " << sum_for_loop << " size: " << input.size() << '\n';
  cout << "mean value of data bytes: " << mean_for_loop << '\n';

  cout << "using accumulate()\n";
  // start stopwatch
  start_timer = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  // accumulate method, but is slow (much slower in g++)
  auto sum_accum =
      std::accumulate(input.begin(), input.end(), 0.0, [](auto current_val, auto each_char) { return current_val + static_cast<unsigned char>(each_char); });

  // stop stopwatch
  cout << std::chrono::duration<double>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start_timer).count() << " s\n";

  auto mean_accum = sum_accum / static_cast<double>(input.size());

  cout << std::fixed << "sum_for_loop: " << sum_accum << " size: " << input.size() << '\n';
  cout << "mean value of data bytes: " << mean_accum << '\n';
}
```

Sample output from 2GB file (`clang++`):

```
using for loop
2.024e-05 s
sum_for_loop: 273805913805 size: 2147483648
mean value of data bytes: 127.500814
using accumulate()
1.317576 s
sum_for_loop: 273805913805.000000 size: 2147483648
mean value of data bytes: 127.500814
```

Sample output from 2GB file (`g++`):

```
using for loop
2.41e-05 s
sum_for_loop: 273805913805 size: 2147483648
mean value of data bytes: 127.500814
using accumulate()
5.269024 s
sum_for_loop: 273805913805.000000 size: 2147483648
mean value of data bytes: 127.500814
```

Sample output from 8GB file (`clang++`):

```
using for loop
1.853e-05 s
sum_for_loop: 1095220441576 size: 8589934592
mean value of data bytes: 127.500440
using accumulate()
5.247585 s
sum_for_loop: 1095220441576.000000 size: 8589934592
mean value of data bytes: 127.500440
```

Sample output from 8GB file (`g++`):

```
using for loop
7.5e-07 s
sum_for_loop: 1095220441576.000000 size: 8589934592
mean value of data bytes: 127.500440
using accumulate()
21.484348 s
sum_for_loop: 1095220441576.000000 size: 8589934592
mean value of data bytes: 127.500440
```

Comment: Whyever would you use an `std::unordered_map`? What's wrong with `std::array<std::size_t, 256>` initialized to 0 as your byte histogram?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just read through the file accumulating all the bytes in an `unsigned long long`?  As long as this doesn't overflow you can then just divide by the file size at the end.

Comment: I'm using an `unordered_map` to calculate the Shannon entropy, which is not part of this code snippet and is working fine. I figured I'd just reuse an existing variable to calculate the mean.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous issues with the code. The first - and the one that is causing your display problem - is that `sum_for_loop` should be a `double`, not an `unsigned long`. The sum is overflowing what can be stored in an unsigned long, resulting in your incorrect result when that happens.

The timers should be started *after* the `cout`, otherwise you're including the output time in the compute time. In addition, the "for loop" elapsed time excludes the time taken to construct `char_map`.

When building `char_map`, you don't need the `if`. If an entry is not found in the map it will be zero initialized. A better approach (since you only have 256 unique values) is to use an indexed vector (remembering to cast the `char` to `unsigned char`).

Comment: @Simog It is also possible that the `static_cast<unsigned char>(item.first) * item.second` calculation is overflowing.

Comment: indeed I was able to fix it with `sum_for_loop += static_cast<unsigned char>(item.first) * static_cast<double>(item.second);`, so I guess the only question remaining is why is `std::accumulate` so much slower in `g++`.

Comment: I just did some benchmarks without the `if` statement, and it happens to be much slower than with the `if` statement.  That said, the `char_map` portion isn't the part I'm concerned about for now.  I need to stick with `unordered_map` for other calculations I need to do, and again, that part isn't the issue I am having with performance (it is with `std::accumulate`.